# Eclipse svn move/rename doesn't work on all-lowercase filenames?

Tags: eclipse, svn, refactoring, move

I am renaming a series of .js files using Refactor -> Rename.

They all work except when I rename a file to an all-lowercase name (i.e. rename `Calendar.js` to `calendar.js`). I get this error:

```
move C:/Users/JohnDeer/workspace/MyApp/WebContent/scripts/ui/Calendar.js C:/Users/JohnDeer/workspace/MyApp/WebContent/scripts/ui/calendar.js
    Path is not a working copy directory
svn: Path 'C:\Users\JohnDeer\workspace\MyApp\WebContent\scripts\ui\calendar.js' is not a directory
```

I checked the ui folder and there is a .svn folder in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that file names are not case sensitive in Windows.  So the lowercase name registers as the original name and maybe when the source file is the same as the destination, the latter is understood as a directory.

As a workaround you can try to use a temporary intermediate file:

- rename Calendar.js to tmp.js
- then rename tmp.js to calendar.js

Another possibility is to rename the file [in the repository](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#case-change) by hand (this can be done using Eclipse's Repository Browsing View as well as from the command line) and then update the project.